# booting windows 8 from external hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, bootable-media

How I can create bootable external hard drive?

or:

### How To Create A USB Bootable Installer Drive For Windows 8

(some websites said that you must format your HDD with FAT32 but as you know 1TB cannot be formatted using FAT32)

[Create bootable External Hard drive](http://dioisme.blogspot.com/2012/11/create-bootable-external-hdd-to-install.html)

but i cant format my external Hard FAT32 for doing this and i dont want to use USB cool disks(flash disks) either

is there any other options to do this?

thank u all.

Comment: What on earth is a "usb cool disk"? Try to use proper terminology.

Comment: What happens when you try to format it as FAT32?   This link says  200GB is ok. another says 127GB..  another says 2TB. MS says a disk size of 8TB is max.  http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t495728-maximum-size-of-fat-32-partition.html  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314463    XP had a 32GB limit apparently.  anyhow, if there is a limitation then you can create a smaller partition like 100GB  You can always increase it later.

Comment: @barlop i will try it.tnx

Comment: (1/2) A 1-TB HDD _can_ be formatted as FAT32... just not under Windows NT (remember that Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10, 11, etc., are all still versions of NT), which has a wholly-artificial 32-GiB limit for formatting partitions as FAT32.  A Linux machine should be able to format the drive as FAT32 just fine; if your computer can boot from a floppy disk, the FORMAT command on a Windows ME boot floppy should also do the trick (Windows 9x versions supporting FAT32 - 95 OSR 2 and later, 98, ME - are not subject to the 32-GiB limit, but 95 and 98 have a bug which keeps them from...

Comment: (2/2) ...working with volumes larger than 127.5 GiB [regardless of filesystem]; this bug was fixed with Windows ME).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's tricky to install Windows on a USB Hard Drive
Here is an article from 2008 on it
http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-to-install-and-boot-windows-on-an-external-usb-hard-drive.116114/

But you can get around that by using an image.
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/73631-35-install-windows-external-drive

I'd add, that you can use Macrium Reflect, to create and restore images, it is freeware,

```
Hello there. I have a simple solution for you if you are familiar with backup & recovery by acronis true image. Then step as bellow:
1. Install windows XP to your internal HDD
2. Make backup your windows XP by acronis true image
3. Create 1 primary partition in your external HDD
4. Recovery windows xp backup file which is already created in step 2 to primary partition in your external HDD.
5. Restart your laptop and press F12 key to get in menu boot select . Then select boot from external HDD
```

There may be a newer method ,  using diskpart and a VHD, which is mentioned at your link
http://dioisme.blogspot.com/2012/11/create-bootable-external-hdd-to-install.html

You can format it as FAT32, and you can always convert it to NTFS later. (I did that with XP).

Windows 7 has a convert command to do that (XP had too apparently)
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/convert-a-hard-disk-or-partition-to-ntfs-format

Comment: and i want to install windows not using WindowsDVD or cool disks.i mean Using external HDDs not for installing windows in extenal hard drive just for booting from it same as when you boot windows from DVD.

Comment: @arashams one doesn't boot windows from a DVD, one boots a windows setup from dvd then installs it somewhere(pretty much,to a hard drive). Then they boot windows from the hard drive.  You can copy a windows setup installation onto a hard drive and then install it from a partition on the hard drive,to another partition on the hard drive. People did that sometimes with windows 98,as CDs were slow and there was no USB installation possible. Can you be more clear as to if you want to boot.Windows, or the Windows setup.Booting a windows setup from DVD(if ever doing that) is pretty much a one-off.

Comment: BTW Regarding what I said, there is such a thing as Bart PE or WinPE.. which is booting windows from a DVD. Anyhow, you want to boot Windows from an external Hard drive, which is easy once it is installed to that hard drive. You'll have to either a)install it to that hard drive(tricky when external) b)use an image(which involves installing  to another hard drive first.  'b' is the easiest way.

Comment: You can format it as FAT32, and you can always convert it to NTFS later. (I did that with XP).  this is not working when partition size is large and i got error partition too large !!!

Comment: @arashams well, if you have that problem in windows 7 or in xp, then make the partition small enough. you can increase the size later, with easeus partition manager http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm   you can convert it with the convert command like convert t: /fs:ntfs where t is the drive letter. Or maybe easeus can convert it to ntfs too. but perhaps makes more sense to only convert and increase it after you've done the whole thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8094/discussion-between-barlop-and-arashams)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a workaround but if you can, put the external HDD into your PC or laptop so that it becomes internal, and install Windows 8 on it. Then remove the HDD and make it external again. Reboot from the external drive.

It boots just fine when I take a HDD with Windows 8 from a PC in my school and connect to my laptop.

My drives are in NTFS format.